# AWK pattern-code-block syntax: how to run code blocks by pattern in AWK?

Tags: awk

Suppose I have a couple of line formats:

```
this:foo ...
that: foo ...
```

And I want to run two different routines for one form or the other:

```
cat text_file \
| awk -F ':' '/:foo/ { # do this } # else print the whole line unchanged' 
| awk -F ':' '/ +foo +/ { # do that } # else print the whole line unchanged'
```

Ideally, I could write:

```
cat text_file \
| awk -F ':' '
   /:foo/ { ... }
   / +foo +/ { ... } 
   ...
   /.*/ { print }
'
```

But things seem to be behaving a lot differently than I expect.  Is there a particular way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
awk '
    /:foo/ { print "do-things"; next }
    /[[:blank:]]+foo[[:blank:]]+/ { print "do-some-other-things"; next }
    { print "do-else" }
' infile
```

Note the `next` statement we used; that is to skip to running the rest of the codes if condition for given block was true; the last block will be execute if none of the two above blocks conditions were met.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want:

```bsh
awk -F: '
    $2 ~ /^[[:blank:]]/ {
        print "2nd field start with space"
    }
    $2 == "" || $2 ~ /^[^[:blank:]]/ {
        print "2nd field does not start with space"
    }
    { print }
' text_file
```